# Json.Net Deserializing list of c# objects throwing error

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization, .net-core-3.1

I have a list of objects in below json format. I would like to deserialize using below code. It is throwing unable to convert to object error. I have tried below three options, but didnt help. `jsoninput` is a `IEnumerable<string>`converted into json object using `ToJson()`.

Error:
`{"Error converting value \"{\"id\":\"11ef2c75-9a6d-4cef-8163-94daad4f8397\",\"name\":\"bracing\",\"lastName\":\"male\",\"profilePictureUrl\":null,\"smallUrl\":null,\"thumbnailUrl\":null,\"country\":null,\"isInvalid\":false,\"userType\":0,\"profilePrivacy\":1,\"chatPrivacy\":1,\"callPrivacy\":0}\" to type 'Api.Models.UserInfo'. Path '[0]', line 1, position 271."}`

```cs
var requests1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsersInfo>(jsoninput);
var requests2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<UserInfo>>(jsoninput);
var requests3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserInfo>>(jsoninput);

//Below are my classes,
public class UsersInfo

{
    public List<UserInfo> UserInfoList { get; set; }
    public UsersInfo()
    {
        UserInfoList = new List<UserInfo>();
    }
}

public class UserInfo
{
    public string Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string LastName { set; get; }
    public string ProfilePictureUrl { set; get; }
    public string SmallUrl { set; get; }
    public string ThumbnailUrl { get; set; }
    public string Country { set; get; }
    public bool IsInvalid { set; get; }
}
```

Below is my json object,

```
["{\"id\":\"11ef2c75-9a6d-4cef-8163-94daad4f8397\",\"name\":\"bracing\",\"lastName\":\"male\",\"profilePictureUrl\":null,\"smallUrl\":null,\"thumbnailUrl\":null,\"country\":null,\"isInvalid\":false}","{\"id\":\"318c0885-2720-472c-ba9e-1d1e120bcf65\",\"name\":\"locomotives\",\"lastName\":\"riddles\",\"profilePictureUrl\":null,\"smallUrl\":null,\"thumbnailUrl\":null,\"country\":null,\"isInvalid\":false}"]
```

Looping through individual items in json input and if i deserialize it like below, it works fine. But i want to deserialize the list fully. Note: `jsoninput` was a `IEnumerable<string>` before i convert in json object.

```
foreach (var re in jsoninput)
{
    var request0 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(re);
}
```

Comment: Please provide the exact error you're seeing.

Comment: But fundamentally your JSON doesn't represent a list of objects - it represents a list consisting of a single string, which itself contains a JSON object.

Comment: Where did you take `jsonInput` from? Escaped like this, it is not a valid json (hence, the error)

Comment: @JonSkeet How should i edit my code to deserialize it?

Comment: @Tu.ma Added my error description.

Comment: Well you'd start by deserializing it to a `List<string>`, because that's what your JSON appears to represent. You can then iterate over each string in the list and deserialize that to a `UserInfo`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your quick comment. I would like to avoid performance bottle neck by avoiding deserializing in a foreach loop. No other way around?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this *would* be a performance bottleneck? If it would be, are you able to serialize to a more sensible format to start with? (A list of strings where each string is JSON is pretty unfortunate.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I dont have evidence now. But we anticipate more data to be loaded in here. Also, i read through and found out DeSerialization is a CPU bound and thereby would like to save infra cost too

Comment: to check which correct format of your json please use this site 
https://app.quicktype.io/  it seems you try to parse string

Comment: how did you get the jsoninput? You have a list of serialized objects instead of serialized list of objects so you need to loop to deserialize them or serialize in correct way

Comment: @MinaFawzy i think json list is in correct format, hence i was able to deserialize one by one item in a foreach loop, as i updated in the question

Comment: @Adassko jsoninput is an output of another method that performs some busines logic and returns IEnumerable<string>. Updated the same in question too.

Comment: @Raj: well, this another method must serialize objects in a loop and returns array of separately serialized object. It should return a single string if it would serialize a list of objects. To deserialize it you need to revert what was done in that another method - if it used loop then you will need to use loop as well

Comment: @Adassko Thanks for your thoughts. The other method returns IEnumerable<string> which is nothing but Dictionary<string,string>.Where(x => x.Value == null).Select(x => x.Key).ToHashSet(). The values in Dictionary<string,string> are -> Key is String, Value is UserInfo object serialized. So, in that case i should deserialize one by one? If not, i should serialize entire list in one shot? Am i right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XpjuL4

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

//Below are my classes,
public class UsersInfo 
{
    public List<UserInfo> UserInfoList { get; set; }
    public UsersInfo()
    {
        UserInfoList = new List<UserInfo>();
    }
}

public class UserInfo
{
    public string Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string LastName { set; get; }
    public string ProfilePictureUrl { set; get; }
    public string SmallUrl { set; get; }
    public string ThumbnailUrl { get; set; }
    public string Country { set; get; }
    public bool IsInvalid { set; get; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        Option1();
        Option2();
    }

    public static void Option1(){
        string json = @"{""UserInfoList"":[
            {""id"":""11ef2c75 - 9a6d - 4cef - 8163 - 94daad4f8397"",""name"":""bracing"",""lastName"":""male"",""profilePictureUrl"":null,""smallUrl"":null,""thumbnailUrl"":null,""country"":null,""isInvalid"":false},
            { ""id"":""318c0885-2720-472c-ba9e-1d1e120bcf65"",""name"":""locomotives"",""lastName"":""riddles"",""profilePictureUrl"":null,""smallUrl"":null,""thumbnailUrl"":null,""country"":null,""isInvalid"":false}
        ]}";
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsersInfo>(json);
        obj.UserInfoList.ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine(e.Id));
    }

    public static void Option2(){
    string json = @"[
            {""id"":""11ef2c75 - 9a6d - 4cef - 8163 - 94daad4f8397"",""name"":""bracing"",""lastName"":""male"",""profilePictureUrl"":null,""smallUrl"":null,""thumbnailUrl"":null,""country"":null,""isInvalid"":false},
            { ""id"":""318c0885-2720-472c-ba9e-1d1e120bcf65"",""name"":""locomotives"",""lastName"":""riddles"",""profilePictureUrl"":null,""smallUrl"":null,""thumbnailUrl"":null,""country"":null,""isInvalid"":false}
        ]";
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserInfo>>(json);
        obj.ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine(e.Id));
    }
}
```

Both work, and are basically very close to what you are doing. You can either serialize it as a list (based on your json, I think that's the closest to your use case, and that's Option 2).

However, put extra attention to the JSON. I had to re-parse your JSON to make it work (https://jsonformatter.org/json-parser is a nice website to do it). For the sake of explaining the example, in C#, `@` means raw string, and in raw string, quotes are escaped with double quotes `""`.

I would expect that the business logic generating this JSON is not correct, if the JSON you pasted is the direct result from it.

**EDIT**
Given the OP's comment:

> Thanks Tu.ma for your thoughts. The other method returns
>   IEnumerable which is nothing but
>   Dictionary.Where(x => x.Value == null).Select(x =>
>   x.Key).ToHashSet(). The values in Dictionary are -> Key
>   is String, Value is UserInfo object serialized. So, in that case i
>   should deserialize one by one? If not, i should serialize entire list
>   in one shot? Am i right? – Raj 12 hours ago

The problem is in the way you are generating the list of UsersInfo. The result from `Dictionary<string,string>.Where(x => x.Value == null).Select(x =>
x.Key).ToHashSet()` is a bunch of strings, not of objects, so you need to serialize them one by one.

If you are worried about the linearity of the approach, you *could* consider [running through it in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942998/running-a-simple-linq-query-in-parallel/27692033). Of course, you need to judge if it fits your application.

```
var userInfoStrings = Dictionary<string,string>.Where(x => x.Value == null).Select(x => x.Key).ToHashSet();

var UserInfoList = userInfoStrings.AsParallel().Select (u => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsersInfo>(u)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Tu.ma for your thoughts. The other method returns IEnumerable<string> which is nothing but Dictionary<string,string>.Where(x => x.Value == null).Select(x => x.Key).ToHashSet(). The values in Dictionary<string,string> are -> Key is String, Value is UserInfo object serialized. So, in that case i should deserialize one by one? If not, i should serialize entire list in one shot? Am i right?

Comment: I see. The result from `Dictionary<string,string>.Where(x => x.Value == null).Select(x => x.Key).ToHashSet()` is a list of strings, not of Users. So you need to serialize one by one. Please see the update in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Pretty much covered my expectation. Will consider AsParallel() method based on our app data and performance.